# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError: The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles

Tags: java, handle, user-object

We have numerous users that use our DSS OWC Application and one of the users is getting the error below:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.InternalError: The current process has used all of its system allowance of handles for Window Manager objects.

Attached the error and also Windows Task Manager showing the max 10,000 user objects. The confusing thing is that many other users at her site are using the same program without issue, so a handle leak did not seem to fit with this particular issue. Tried upgrading and then downgrading Java versions to match other users.

[image: Error]

[image: Task Manager]

Answer (score 1):

This exception is resulted because of some memory leak. Try going through again and find what is causing this. I'm sure you can fix it.

Comment: While this may help OP, it's better to add more details, explanation, examples, etc.  Please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)